# member.kick function in discord.py not working

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

This is the code for my kick command in my discord bot:

```
@client.command(aliases=['k'])
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members = True)
async def kick(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason = "Reason not provided"):
    serverName = ctx.message.guild.name
    await member.send("You have been kicked from the " + serverName + ". Reason: " + reason)
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send("User has been kicked")
```

However, when I call this command I get no output. I tried print debugging the code and it always stops at the line `await member.kick(reason=reason)`. This is the exception I get:

```
>> Traceback (most recent call last):
>> File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 333, in _run_event
>>     await coro(*args, **kwargs)
>>   File "bot.py", line 41, in on_message
>>     if ":" in msg.content[0] and ":" in msg.content[-1]:
>> IndexError: string index out of range
```

Could someone help me out to fix this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "it stops at the line"? Does it throw an exception? If so, what exception?

Comment: @ThomasKowalski I added the exception I received to the question now

Comment: This exception does not seem to be related to this command...

Comment: please check this doc [link](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#a-minimal-bot)

Comment: @ThomasKowalski every time I run the command that pops up

Comment: Don't you have an `on_message` event listener on line 41?

Comment: Yep, I do. But for some reason whenever i run this command or even my ban command, it always shows an exception leading to this line.

Comment: That's because `on_message` is also triggered when a command is matched. That means your `kick` issue is probably unrelated (even though I'm quite surprised about that exception, since I can't see a case where the contents of a message would be empty...)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably overriding your command in the `on_message`.
If you append this the right way in your `on_message` it should work. (If that was the mistake)

```
await self.process_commands(message)
```

You can find the documentation about `process_commands` [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=process_commands#discord.ext.commands.Bot.process_commands).

As your error is giving an `IndexError` it means that you are trying to parse characters that don't exist. (In your if statement on line 41 `msg.content[index]`)

Comment: I don't think that's the issue here; OP has said that execution goes up to the call to `member.kick`